# mysql locking read (for update & lock in share mode not really working for what I want)

Tags: mysql, locking

I have table

```
tasks
id, started_at, ...
1, 2017-01-01 10:00:00
2, 2017-01-01 10:00:00 
3, NULL
4, NULL
...

SELECT * FROM TASKS WHERE started_at IS NULL LIMIT 10
```

save ids of above query to ids variable

```
UPDATE tasks SET started_at = <<NOW>> WHERE id IN <<ids>>
```

Now I need to make sure that no other process reads the same ids before the update has happened.

I tried:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE requested_at IS NULL LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

and

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE requested_at IS NULL FOR UPDATE;
```

However I still got the same resultset when querying from another connection even though I have not finished the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `UPDATE` is where the locking should be taking place, because this is the point at which you don't want anyone else querying and getting back incomplete/inconsistent data.  So you could try performing the `UPDATE` as follows:

```
LOCK TABLES tasks WRITE;
    UPDATE tasks SET started_at = <<NOW>> WHERE id IN <<ids>>
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Another option would be to perform the update inside a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE tasks SET started_at = <<NOW>> WHERE id IN <<ids>>
COMMIT;
```

In either case, the records being updated should not be accessible by anyone else until the `UPDATE` has completed.

Comment: I actually already want the lock to happen during the SELECT, because I need to make sure that another select does not get the same ids.

Comment: @Chris Your requirement is unclear then.  You would typically use locking during an update to ensure that other sessions do not see inconsistent data in the records being updated.  Specifically, you'd use locking to make sure that the updates are seen as _atomic_, either the entire update happened, or it has not yet happened.